# Do we have any function that is used to unprotect the sheet in excel using apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to implement the code in java apache-poi 3.11, that is used to unprotect(remove protection) the sheet in excel that is already password protected. do we have any function to do this?

Comment: [Docs](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)

Comment: I have tried with decryption process mentioned but that is helpful if I want read the data that is presented in password protected sheet. But I want to unprotect sheet means I want to remove the password of the sheet? Is this possible?

Comment: Create a new unprotected sheet and copy the data

Comment: Dont we have any other option to unprotect the existing sheet?

Comment: Not with apache-poi. You can always do it manually if you find that option better

Comment: Yes, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67188074/9727918