# Is there any way to unprotect XSSFSheet password?

Tags: java, apache-poi, worksheet

I am using XSSFSheet class of package org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel and using the below code to password protect the sheet.

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheetName");
sheet.protectSheet("password");
```

Is there any way to unprotect the sheet using the same class(XSSFSheet) ?

Comment: The javadoc says "_Pass null to remove protection_" - see [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#protectSheet-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @andrewjames Your answer makes sense but  what if we are accessing the protected file from another API/Program ?

Comment: You need the password to access the protected resource. For example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042694/how-can-i-access-password-protected-excel-workbook-in-java-using-poi-api). Regarding "_another API_" - if you have a specific API in mind (i.e. something other than POI), you can ask a specific question about that (assuming it has not already been asked and answered).

Answer (score 1):

Like This

```
sheet.protectSheet(null);
```